# Passar array por Ajax e receber em script PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Preciso passar um `Array` por *Ajax* para ler ele em um script *PHP*.

**Código Javascript**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "vendas_funcoes.php",
    data: arrayItens,
    success: function(msg){
        console.log("ok");
    }
});
```

Já tentei usar o exemplo seguinte que vi, porém não deu certo. Também já tentei usar `stringify` e não rolou.

**vendas_funcoes.php**:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

    // usar foreach para ler o array
    foreach($data as $d){
        echo $d;
    }
?>
```

Como recebo esse `Array` no script *PHP* para que eu possa manipular ele ? O código acima aparentemente não entra no `foreach` que tenho em meu script `.php`.

Comment: Não seria `data: {"data": arrayItens}` no JQuery?

Comment: Para você pegar o valor desta forma "$_POST['data']" coloque o "data" do jquery da seguinte forma data : { data : arrayItens }, ou seja se definir "data" no post do php você pega "data", caso queria outro nome você pode fazer data : { teste: arrayItens } e então no php você vai ter que colocar $_POST['teste']

Comment: Obrigado, @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Dessa forma entrará no meu 'foreach' ? Como posso testar para ver se estou recebendo o array mesmo ?

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa dar um `json_decode` no seu *POST*, o default do `contentType` do ajax é `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, que vai fazer a requisicação como se fosse um formulario *HTML*.

Desta forma:

```
<?php
    $data = stripslashes($_POST);

    foreach($data as $d){
        echo $d;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Aparentemente o array vem como vazio dessa forma, pois não entra no foreach